# Update a fragment whenever page selected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite, android-context

I have 2 fragments in my App's MainActivity. One fragment will read data from Bluetooth Device and create a Database. Other will display this data (in BarGraph). It is working fine. But, the BarGraph is not updating dynamically when new data comes. I implemented a PageChangeListener such that if the user changes to the BarGraph fragment, it should get updated as follows

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mSectionsPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager, position);
                if(position == 1){
                    AnalyticsFragment.newInstance(position).updateChart(getApplicationContext());
                    //af = new AnalyticsFragment();
                    //af.updateChart();
                }
        }..
```

AnalyticsFragment(BarGrapg one) has a method updateChart which updates my BarGraph by reading from the DataBase

```
public void updateChart(Context context){
        //Getting weight and time from db
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(context == null)    //This is because I get NullPointerError here
            return;
        FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(context);
        list = mDbHelper.getAllWeight();
        if (list.isEmpty()){
            Log.w(tag, "List of weights is empty!!");
            return;
        }
        drawgraph(list);
    }
```

But, it doesn't get updated when new data comes. Am I doing anything wrong?

P.S. This is certainly not a duplicate question. I have gone through all simular ones and found them un-helpful. I keep getting this irritating error always

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this isn't how you access your `Fragment` that is `attached` to your `Adapter`, to access and update it, you could use below code instead of creating `newInstance` every time you scroll.

```
AnalyticsFragment fragment = (AnalyticsFragment)  viewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewPager,0/* position of your fragment */);
```

now you could do

```
fragment.updateChart();
```

do yourself a favour and never pass `Context` from your `Activity` to your `Fragment`.

remove the `context` from the method params and use `getContext();` of the `Fragment` instead as the `context` `param` is no longer needed.